# Query Regarding Apache Setup

Tags: apache

I have 2 websites on a Ubuntu 14.04 Server with Apache. The websites lie in `/var/www.` I have bought a couple of domains from Godaddy. I have linked the domain and the machine's IP.

Lets say I have **abc.com** and **xyz.com**. When a user tries to access **abc.com**, I need to show him the website under `/var/www/abc/index.html` and similarly for **xyz.com**.

I researched and found that under `/etc/apache2/` there is some settings file I need to change in order to do it but I am not sure what to do. Could anybody give me a hint on how I can achieve this?

A detailed answer can be lot helpful for understanding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run multiple sites on one apache instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339044/how-to-run-multiple-sites-on-one-apache-instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a lot of research, I have found the answer to my question. I will share the steps I did to solve it.

1. cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
2. sudo cp 0* abc.com.conf
3. sudo nano abc.com.conf
4. sudo a2ensite abc.com.conf
5. sudo service apache2 restart

The contents of abc.com.conf should be something similar to below code and don't touch anything else.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@abc.com
    ServerName abc.com
    ServerAlias www.abc.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/abc/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Similarly do so for the next website also.

Comment: This is all debian specific.  It's  basic virtual host configuration.

Comment: Yes true that. Just didn't know the way to do in Ubuntu