# Host 2 application under one domain Apache HTTPD

Tags: ruby, apache, tomcat, dashing

I'm trying to configure Apache HTTPD 2.4 to front two different applications being hosted on the same server.

App1 is reachable on port 8080 (Tomcat)

```
mysingledomain.com:8080
```

App2 is reachable on port 3030 (Ruby [Dashing])

```
mysingledomain.com:3030
```

What I want to do is reach them respectively as `mysingledomain.com/App1` and `mysingledomain.com/App2`

My situation is a lot like how this question start:
[Host 2 Sites in HTTPD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339044/how-to-run-multiple-sites-on-one-apache-instance)

These are both SPA applications but I'm getting quite confused on how to set this up when I do not have a DocumentRoot to separate the configuration.

How would I setup HTTPD to front the HTTP requests in this manner?

I was able to configure the ruby application to adhere to a subpath with the following configuration, but this affects the other:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyRequests On # <---- WARNING DO NOT DO THIS
  ProxyVia On
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  RewriteEngine On

  ProxyPass "/app2"  "http://192.168.0.62:3030/" retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse "/app2/"  "http://192.168.0.62/"

  RewriteRule   "^/assets/(.*)"    "/app2/assets/$1"  [R]
  RewriteRule   "^/views/(.*)"    "/app2/views/$1"  [R]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: **DO NOT USE `ProxyRequests On`. This will enable forward-proxying which is NOT what you want.**

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Thanks, you're right I didn't need that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysingledomain.com
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  ProxyPass /App1/  http://127.0.0.1:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse /App1/  http://127.0.0.1:8080/

  ProxyPass /App2/  http://127.0.0.1:3030/
  ProxyPassReverse /App2/  http://127.0.0.1:3030/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: But the how cant I get setup the `RewriteCond` for this. The `RewriteRule` should only affect the Ruby application (App2).

Comment: There was nothing about Rewrite in your question :). What URL exactly do you want to rewrite, and to what?

Comment: I'd like to rewrite the response coming back from `http://192.168.0.62:3030/`. The Rewrite in the question does that, but seems  The problem is, the response header says the referrer is 192.168.0.62 so i had to use the Reverse definition from the question

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve (beside simple proxying to two backend apps, depending on the URI): mod_rewrite is rewriting requests, not responses; Referer: is request header, not response header. What exactly doesn't work if you just use the ProxyPass directives as above, can you give an example?

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that my issue isn't the app server as much as it is the application I'm trying to host.